# Multiplication by Individual Place Value in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multiplication

I have two non-negative numbers represented as arrays of digits that could be of different lengths and I want to multiply them without converting to string using stoll because that limits the input size.

I can get it to work for cases like 900 * 9, but not 11 * 11.

This is what I have so far:

```
  #include <iostream>
  int main() {

    int a[100], b[100], product[200]; // required to use
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      cin >> a[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
      cin >> b[i];
    }

    int temp2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      int temp1 = temp2*10; // i think it might be this line that doesn't always work but i don't know what I should change it to
      for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        temp2 = a[i] * b[j] + temp1;
        cout << temp2 << endl;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: The way to do this is to not have free-floating arrays in your code, but to write or use a pre-existing BigInteger class. Search for "BigInteger implementation c++" or "BigInt Implementation c++" to see some examples.

Comment: If you are required to do this the hard way, at least see if you can use `std::vector` or `std::array`. Raw arrays are old magic and have a lot of gotchas.

Comment: Think through the process of doing the multiplication using pencil and paper. Try to reproduce the logic in code.

Comment: I recommend completing the code. Right now if I want to try out the sample you've given I have to write all of the scaffolding to make it compile and run. In doing that I'm changing the parameters of your problem and could accidentally fix the bug or insert a  new one. Use [mcve] as inspiration because if you do the MRE right, you'll probably find the bug yourself.

Comment: I think found the bug (see post edits) but I'm stuck on how to fix it and I'm required to use the arrays given.

Comment: @John It is pretty obvious from the context, that this is exercise. Writing a biginteger implementation is, IMNSHO, quite good exercise when learning programming.

Comment: @hyde, I agree, which is why I suggested OP look up prior implementations. I was making the assumption that they knew the problem they needed to solve, but didn't know the right terminology.

Comment: @nikki are you stuck on the algorithm or the implementation? If you know the algorithm and are just having trouble getting your implementation to match, then use your debugger to step through the code and see where the implementation diverges from the algorithm. If you don't know the algorithm, work it out on paper with small numbers first.

Comment: @John I don't know how to manage the addition before the final product as in (11*1)+(11*1)*10 = 121. I know right now this doesn't work because it's still doing 1*1*10, which is just ten, but converting to string, concatenating, converting back to int to operate just seems really messy, I think there's a neater solution I'm not seeing.

Comment: What are the possible values each value in your array can have? `0` thru `9`? Are these base-10 numbers?

Comment: oh!! i've solved a similar problem before for addition using division and modulo! got it!

Comment: @nikkibeck -- Each element in the array is probably just a digit from 0 - 9, is that right?  So why are you doing all of this concatenation, converting to string, etc.?  Do you do that when you multiply "by hand"?  All you should be doing is figuring out how to multiply a single digit of array "b" by a single digit of array "a", adding the carry, getting the modulus of that result, storing it in some temp array "c", and getting the new carry by dividing the sub-answer by 10, then move on to the next digit in array "a".  **Exactly** how you do this in elementary school.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed your code in the solution below. The solution is stored in the `product` array and then moved to a `vector<int>` called `solution` with `size` equal to the exact number of digits as the final answer and is printed to console after the program finishes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int a[100], b[100], product[200]; // required to use
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
        product[i] = 0;
    }
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        cin >> b[i];
    }

    int lineDigit = 0;
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int lineSum = 0;
        for (int j = m - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            int digit = (m - j) + 1;

            int digitProd = a[i] * b[j];
            int tens = digitProd / 10;
            int ones = digitProd % 10;
            product[digit + lineDigit] += ones;
            product[digit + lineDigit + 1] += tens;

            product[digit + lineDigit + 1] += product[digit + lineDigit] / 10;
            product[digit + lineDigit] %= 10;
        }

        ++lineDigit;
    }

    bool foundNonZero = false;
    vector<int> solution;
    for (int i = 199; i >= 2; --i) {
        if (!foundNonZero) {
            if (product[i] != 0) {
                foundNonZero = true;
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        solution.push_back(product[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < solution.size(); ++i) {
        cout << solution[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

There were a couple of simple arithmetic errors in your code. It won't be very elucidating to go over it; just keep thinking about how multiplication is done by hand and try to get the logic right.